# how to reach bundle.js functions from webpack output

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a question which kinda confuses me a lot so I wanted to share it here. In my typescript project, I have an entry point called index.ts

Using this index.ts I import other class and that class also calls others via imports.

In order to bond all files to a single file, I'm using web pack and at the end, I'm getting a bundle.js file. The question is when I include this bundle.js file into my HTML page which is inside a folder, and I try to reach this bundle.js, js file doesn't suggest me any functions or something. however, if I write the name of the function manually and check it on the browser it works. Following I'll share my code and make it more clear:)

this is my index.ts file

```js
import {Location} from './Location'

let a = new Location(10,29)

export function start() {
    a.createLocationKeyMaterial(5)
}

export function deneme() {
    console.log("ahmet")
}
```

this is my webpack.config file

```js
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.ts',
   output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: __dirname,
      libraryTarget: 'var',
      library: 'lockum',
   },
   module: {
      rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
         },
         {
            test: /\.hbs$/,
            loader: 'handlebars-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                helperDirs: [
                  path.resolve(__dirname, "template", 'helpers')
                ]
              }
         }
      ]
   },
   resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".hbs"]
   }
}
```

the html page I call

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script src="../bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <script src= "letssee.ts"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
lockum.start()
```

so here when I type soemthing into example.js file, if i write lockum it suggests me that but after lockum when I type "." it doesnt suggest me any fucntions.

and the content of bundle.js as follow

```js
var lockum = function(t) {
  var i = {};

  function n(e) {
    if (i[e]) return i[e].exports;
    var o = i[e] = {
      i: e,
      l: !1,
      exports: {}
    };
    return t[e].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, n), o.l = !0, o.exports
  }
  return n.m = t, n.c = i, n.d = function(t, i, e) {
    n.o(t, i) || Object.defineProperty(t, i, {
      configurable: !1,
      enumerable: !0,
      get: e
    })
  }, n.r = function(t) {
    Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    })
  }, n.n = function(t) {
    var i = t && t.__esModule ? function() {
      return t.default
    } : function() {
      return t
    };
    return n.d(i, "a", i), i
  }, n.o = function(t, i) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, i)
  }, n.p = "", n(n.s = 2)
}([function(t, i, n) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(i, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
  });
  var e = function() {
    function t() {}
    return t.calculateLocationKeyMaterial = function(t, i, n) {
      if (null == t || null == i) throw new Error("Location information has not been fetched.");
      var e = this.includeToleranceDistance(t, i, n);
      return console.log("key derivation function input should be: " + e), e
    }, t.includeToleranceDistance = function(t, i, n) {
      var e = !1,
        o = !1;
      return t < 0 ? t *= -1 : e = !0, i < 0 && (i *= -1, o = !0), t = this.convertToDegreesDecimalMinutes(t), i = this.convertToDegreesDecimalMinutes(i), t *= 1e4, i *= 1e4, e ? (t = Math.floor(t / (5.4 * n)), t = this.includeLocationSignBits(t, !0)) : (t = Math.floor(t / (5.4 * n)), t = this.includeLocationSignBits(t, !1)), o ? (i = Math.floor(i / (6 * n)), i = this.includeLocationSignBits(i, !0)) : (i = Math.floor(i / (6 * n)), i = this.includeLocationSignBits(i, !1)), t.toString() + i.toString()
    }, t.convertToDegreesDecimalMinutes = function(t) {
      var i = Math.floor(t),
        n = parseFloat((t % 1 * 60).toFixed(5).substring(0, 7));
      return parseFloat(i.toString() + n.toString())
    }, t.includeLocationSignBits = function(t, i) {
      return i ? 201326592 + t : (1 << 27) + t
    }, t.createLocationMaterials = function(t, i, n) {
      var e, o, r, c, a = !1,
        u = !1,
        l = new Array;
      if (t < 0 ? t *= -1 : t > 0 && (a = !0), i < 0 && (i *= -1, u = !0), t = this.convertToDegreesDecimalMinutes(t), i = this.convertToDegreesDecimalMinutes(i), t *= 1e4, i *= 1e4, a) {
        var s = t = Math.floor(t / (5.4 * n));
        t = this.includeLocationSignBits(t, !0), e = s - 1, e = this.includeLocationSignBits(e, !0), o = s + 1, o = this.includeLocationSignBits(o, !0)
      } else {
        s = t = Math.floor(t / (5.4 * n));
        t = this.includeLocationSignBits(t, !1), e = s - 1, e = this.includeLocationSignBits(e, !1), o = s + 1, o = this.includeLocationSignBits(o, !1)
      }
      if (u) {
        s = i = Math.floor(i / (6 * n));
        i = this.includeLocationSignBits(i, !0), r = s - 1, r = this.includeLocationSignBits(r, !0), c = s + 1, c = this.includeLocationSignBits(c, !0)
      } else {
        s = i = Math.floor(i / (6 * n));
        i = this.includeLocationSignBits(i, !1), r = s - 1, r = this.includeLocationSignBits(r, !1), c = s + 1, c = this.includeLocationSignBits(c, !1)
      }
      return l[0] = e.toString() + r.toString(), l[1] = e.toString() + i.toString(), l[2] = e.toString() + c.toString(), l[3] = t.toString() + r.toString(), l[4] = t.toString() + i.toString(), l[5] = t.toString() + c.toString(), l[6] = o.toString() + r.toString(), l[7] = o.toString() + i.toString(), l[8] = o.toString() + c.toString(), l
    }, t
  }();
  i.LocationHelper = e
}, function(t, i, n) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(i, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
  });
  var e = n(0),
    o = function() {
      function t(t, i) {
        this.latitude = parseFloat(t.toFixed(6)), this.longitude = parseFloat(i.toFixed(6)), console.log(this.latitude), console.log(this.longitude)
      }
      return t.prototype.createLocationKeyMaterial = function(t) {
        return e.LocationHelper.calculateLocationKeyMaterial(this.latitude, this.longitude, t)
      }, t.prototype.createLocationKeyMaterials = function(t) {
        return e.LocationHelper.createLocationMaterials(this.latitude, this.longitude, t)
      }, t
    }();
  i.Location = o
}, function(t, i, n) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(i, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
  });
  var e = new(n(1).Location)(10, 29);
  i.start = function() {
    e.createLocationKeyMaterial(5)
  }, i.deneme = function() {
    console.log("ahmet")
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript's support for analyzing JavaScript is not smart enough to determine the type of the `lockum` variable from the complex JavaScript code generated by Webpack.  Instead, you can copy `lockum` to a new variable and give it the type of your `index.ts` module using a [JSDoc comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript).  Add the following to the top of `example.js`:

```
/** @type {typeof import("./index")} */
var lockum2 = lockum;
```

(Adjust the path to point to `index.ts`.)

However, you might be better off just adding the code you planned to put in `example.js` to a TypeScript module.

Comment: Hey Matt thanks for the heads up, however this unfortunality didn't work. To be honest, what I'm trying to achieve is that compiling my multiple typescript files into a single js file ( I'm trying to create a library) and serve everything from this single js file however it really seems to be a pain in the ass, I've spent several days , didn't work.

Comment: How far did you get?  If you hold Control and click on the `./index`, do you jump to `index.ts`?  If you hover over `lockum2`, what type is displayed?

Comment: Hi, I tried and browser tells me that lockum is not defined in this case and it also says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: That's strange: if `bundle.js` is as shown in the question, there's no way you should be getting `lockum` undefined after `bundle.js` directly creates it.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you?  Maybe there is something else involved that you haven't described in the question.  On what file and line is the SyntaxError reported?

Comment: Dear Matt,
First of all thank you very much for your sincere guidance! I added the sample project to github https://github.com/lifeanddeath/typescriptBundle  , if you would checkout it and tell me what I do wrong, I'd eternally appreciate that, like I said before, bundle.js is created and I just wanted to try my library locally in the example folder to see how it works.. For example as you can see from html file, I call the bundle.js first and then I want to reach this start and deneme functions from my bundle. however they are not being shown. thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I downloaded the repository and opened `example/example.html` in a browser without making any changes.  I don't get any errors and I can see in the developer console that the `lockum2` variable has been correctly defined.  So I don't know what's going wrong for you.  Re `example.js` not giving you suggestions of your functions: the import path just needs to be changed to `"../../src/index"` and then it works for me.  The whole point is that the path should refer to your TypeScript code, because `bundle.js` is too complicated for the TypeScript language service to analyze.

Comment: Dear Matt,  I'm so sorry to bother you with my question but, I dont get couple of points. so upon reading your answer( I really really thank you so much) I went and downloaded the exact same project again from github. I opened browser without touching anything and changed the path as you suggested. Then when I write lockum2 on the console I see that, its being shown and also the function and if i run the deneme function it returns me in first line ahmet(the expected output) and the second line says undefined. if i call start method it just returns undefined. do you mean path at @type part?

Comment: I'm so sorry to ask much but, also if i come to visual studio code ide, now I see the functions but if i call them through the ide, nothing is being shown on the console, it only works when i call it in the browser... Dear Matt, I have to submit my master project soon and this is the only problem I have left, if you could help me via team viewer or gmail I'd love to thank you so so much, do I have a chance to contact you via any form please? its a matter of life and death for me

Comment: Re the `undefined` return from `start`, you are missing a `return` before `a.createLocationKeyMaterial(5,9)` in `index.ts`.  If I add `lockum2.deneme();` to `example.js`, I see `ahmet` in the console as expected.  Likewise if I make the correction to `start`, run webpack, and add `console.log(lockum2.start());` to `example.js`, I see `14`, which looks right.  (Without the `console.log`, the `14` is just returned and thrown away.)  Hopefully that was all you were missing.  Otherwise, I can help you troubleshoot further if you contact me on Google Hangouts (matt@mattmccutchen.net).

Comment: For the record, it seems that the code was working after the changes from my previous comment, and on our call, we just cleared up the understanding of the role of tsc, webpack, type declarations, and publishing and consuming packages.